# Set positions of different widgets, buttons, etc and create lineedit with horizontal scrollbar

Tags: c++, qt

In the window below you can see how my ui looks so far.
Now I have the following two problems:

1. I want that the right half of the window has a (almost) fixed size when in- or decreasing the window in size. The left part (the big square with the scrollbars) should fill the rest of the window. It doesn't have to be a square. It should occupy all the rectangular space that's left. When decreasing the window in size, the right half could also become a bit smaller, but I want to set a minimum to that, so the buttons aren't ridiculously small. Vice versa when increasing the window in size.

**EDIT**

And how do I set the "origin point" of e.g. the right halt to the top right corner? So if I enlarge the window to the right the right half sticks to the right side and makes space for the white rectangle so spread.

When I decrease the windows size:
[image]

When I increase the windows size:
[image]
**EDIT END**

2. And I'd like to have a `QLineEdit`, can be any text line format as long as it looks like a single line, with a horizontal scrollbar beneath `Dropdown`, where it reads `Textfeld`. The way it is below, is just a simple `QLineEdit` with a horizontal `QScrollBar` beneath it, but they are still seperate and do not interact with each other.

I've looked on stackoverflow and on other websites, but I've never found a solution for any of those :/

[image: exampleWindow]

If I try to but `QLineEdit` inside `QScrollArea` it looks like this and doesn't work: [image]

That's  the associated .ui:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>patchbot_game</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="patchbot_game">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>779</width>
    <height>717</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>patchbot_game</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QScrollBar" name="verticalScrollBar_2">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>351</x>
      <y>59</y>
      <width>16</width>
      <height>491</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="orientation">
     <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="selectNewColonyButton">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>610</x>
      <y>6</y>
      <width>150</width>
      <height>50</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="minimumSize">
     <size>
      <width>150</width>
      <height>50</height>
     </size>
    </property>
    <property name="maximumSize">
     <size>
      <width>150</width>
      <height>50</height>
     </size>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>11</pointsize>
      <weight>75</weight>
      <bold>true</bold>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Andere Kolonie ...</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QScrollBar" name="horizontalScrollBar_2">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>20</x>
      <y>550</y>
      <width>331</width>
      <height>16</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="orientation">
     <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="currentColonyLabel">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>20</x>
      <y>20</y>
      <width>341</width>
      <height>16</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>10</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Aktuelle Kolonie: Lithium-Stollen 13-A</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QScrollArea" name="scrollArea">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>610</x>
      <y>190</y>
      <width>130</width>
      <height>73</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="frameShape">
     <enum>QFrame::NoFrame</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="frameShadow">
     <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="lineWidth">
     <number>9</number>
    </property>
    <property name="midLineWidth">
     <number>10</number>
    </property>
    <property name="horizontalScrollBarPolicy">
     <enum>Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="widgetResizable">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
    <widget class="QWidget" name="scrollAreaWidgetContents_3">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>0</x>
       <y>0</y>
       <width>130</width>
       <height>59</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <widget class="QLineEdit" name="botCommandEdit">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>0</x>
        <y>10</y>
        <width>130</width>
        <height>50</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Fixed">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="minimumSize">
       <size>
        <width>130</width>
        <height>50</height>
       </size>
      </property>
      <property name="maximumSize">
       <size>
        <width>130</width>
        <height>50</height>
       </size>
      </property>
      <property name="font">
       <font>
        <pointsize>20</pointsize>
        <weight>75</weight>
        <bold>true</bold>
       </font>
      </property>
      <property name="focusPolicy">
       <enum>Qt::StrongFocus</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="toolTip">
       <string>&lt;html&gt;&lt;head/&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;br/&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</string>
      </property>
      <property name="autoFillBackground">
       <bool>false</bool>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>1234567890987654323456789</string>
      </property>
      <property name="maxLength">
       <number>32762</number>
      </property>
      <property name="frame">
       <bool>true</bool>
      </property>
      <property name="echoMode">
       <enum>QLineEdit::Normal</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="cursorPosition">
       <number>25</number>
      </property>
      <property name="alignment">
       <set>Qt::AlignLeading|Qt::AlignLeft|Qt::AlignVCenter</set>
      </property>
      <property name="dragEnabled">
       <bool>false</bool>
      </property>
      <property name="readOnly">
       <bool>true</bool>
      </property>
      <property name="placeholderText">
       <string>Textfeld</string>
      </property>
      <property name="clearButtonEnabled">
       <bool>false</bool>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </widget>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QWidget" name="formLayoutWidget">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>420</x>
      <y>310</y>
      <width>311</width>
      <height>201</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <layout class="QFormLayout" name="formLayout">
     <property name="fieldGrowthPolicy">
      <enum>QFormLayout::AllNonFixedFieldsGrow</enum>
     </property>
     <property name="horizontalSpacing">
      <number>20</number>
     </property>
     <property name="verticalSpacing">
      <number>10</number>
     </property>
     <property name="leftMargin">
      <number>15</number>
     </property>
     <property name="topMargin">
      <number>0</number>
     </property>
     <property name="rightMargin">
      <number>15</number>
     </property>
     <property name="bottomMargin">
      <number>10</number>
     </property>
     <item row="0" column="0">
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="startButton">
       <property name="minimumSize">
        <size>
         <width>130</width>
         <height>50</height>
        </size>
       </property>
       <property name="maximumSize">
        <size>
         <width>130</width>
         <height>50</height>
        </size>
       </property>
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <pointsize>15</pointsize>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Start</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="1" column="0">
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="singleStepButton">
       <property name="minimumSize">
        <size>
         <width>130</width>
         <height>50</height>
        </size>
       </property>
       <property name="maximumSize">
        <size>
         <width>130</width>
         <height>50</height>
        </size>
       </property>
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <pointsize>15</pointsize>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Einzelschritt</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="1" column="1">
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="autoButton">
       <property name="minimumSize">
        <size>
         <width>130</width>
         <height>50</height>
        </size>
       </property>
       <property name="maximumSize">
        <size>
         <width>130</width>
         <height>50</height>
        </size>
       </property>
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <pointsize>15</pointsize>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Automatik</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="2" column="1">
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="pauseButton">
       <property name="minimumSize">
        <size>
         <width>130</width>
         <height>50</height>
        </size>
       </property>
       <property name="maximumSize">
        <size>
         <width>130</width>
         <height>50</height>
        </size>
       </property>
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <pointsize>15</pointsize>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Anhalten</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="0" column="1">
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="abortButton">
       <property name="minimumSize">
        <size>
         <width>130</width>
         <height>50</height>
        </size>
       </property>
       <property name="maximumSize">
        <size>
         <width>130</width>
         <height>50</height>
        </size>
       </property>
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <pointsize>15</pointsize>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Abbruch</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
    </layout>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QComboBox" name="repeatDropdown">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>610</x>
      <y>100</y>
      <width>130</width>
      <height>50</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="minimumSize">
     <size>
      <width>130</width>
      <height>50</height>
     </size>
    </property>
    <property name="maximumSize">
     <size>
      <width>130</width>
      <height>50</height>
     </size>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>15</pointsize>
      <weight>75</weight>
      <italic>false</italic>
      <bold>true</bold>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="focusPolicy">
     <enum>Qt::WheelFocus</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="layoutDirection">
     <enum>Qt::LeftToRight</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="currentText">
     <string>1</string>
    </property>
    <property name="insertPolicy">
     <enum>QComboBox::NoInsert</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="frame">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
    <item>
     <property name="text">
      <string>1</string>
     </property>
    </item>
    <item>
     <property name="text">
      <string>2</string>
     </property>
    </item>
    <item>
     <property name="text">
      <string>3</string>
     </property>
    </item>
    <item>
     <property name="text">
      <string>4</string>
     </property>
    </item>
    <item>
     <property name="text">
      <string>5</string>
     </property>
    </item>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QWidget" name="layoutWidget_2">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>420</x>
      <y>100</y>
      <width>164</width>
      <height>164</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_3">
     <property name="sizeConstraint">
      <enum>QLayout::SetFixedSize</enum>
     </property>
     <item row="0" column="1">
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="upButton">
       <property name="minimumSize">
        <size>
         <width>50</width>
         <height>50</height>
        </size>
       </property>
       <property name="maximumSize">
        <size>
         <width>50</width>
         <height>50</height>
        </size>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string/>
       </property>
       <property name="icon">
        <iconset resource="grafics.qrc">
         <normaloff>:/grafics/grafics/pfeile/pfeil_oben.tga</normaloff>:/grafics/grafics/pfeile/pfeil_oben.tga</iconset>
       </property>
       <property name="iconSize">
        <size>
         <width>50</width>
         <height>50</height>
        </size>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="0" column="2">
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="deleteButton">
       <property name="minimumSize">
        <size>
         <width>50</width>
         <height>50</height>
        </size>
       </property>
       <property name="maximumSize">
        <size>
         <width>50</width>
         <height>50</height>
        </size>
       </property>
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <pointsize>15</pointsize>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>&lt;</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="1" column="0">
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="leftButton">
       <property name="minimumSize">
        <size>
         <width>50</width>
         <height>50</height>
        </size>
       </property>
       <property name="maximumSize">
        <size>
         <width>50</width>
         <height>50</height>
        </size>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string/>
       </property>
       <property name="icon">
        <iconset resource="grafics.qrc">
         <normaloff>:/grafics/grafics/pfeile/pfeil_links.tga</normaloff>:/grafics/grafics/pfeile/pfeil_links.tga</iconset>
       </property>
       <property name="iconSize">
        <size>
         <width>50</width>
         <height>50</height>
        </size>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="1" column="1">
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="waitButton">
       <property name="minimumSize">
        <size>
         <width>50</width>
         <height>50</height>
        </size>
       </property>
       <property name="maximumSize">
        <size>
         <width>50</width>
         <height>50</height>
        </size>
       </property>
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <pointsize>15</pointsize>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>W</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="1" column="2">
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="rightButton">
       <property name="minimumSize">
        <size>
         <width>50</width>
         <height>50</height>
        </size>
       </property>
       <property name="maximumSize">
        <size>
         <width>50</width>
         <height>50</height>
        </size>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string/>
       </property>
       <property name="icon">
        <iconset resource="grafics.qrc">
         <normaloff>:/grafics/grafics/pfeile/pfeil_rechts.tga</normaloff>:/grafics/grafics/pfeile/pfeil_rechts.tga</iconset>
       </property>
       <property name="iconSize">
        <size>
         <width>50</width>
         <height>50</height>
        </size>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="2" column="1">
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="downButton">
       <property name="minimumSize">
        <size>
         <width>50</width>
         <height>50</height>
        </size>
       </property>
       <property name="maximumSize">
        <size>
         <width>50</width>
         <height>50</height>
        </size>
       </property>
       <property name="layoutDirection">
        <enum>Qt::LeftToRight</enum>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string/>
       </property>
       <property name="icon">
        <iconset resource="grafics.qrc">
         <normaloff>:/grafics/grafics/pfeile/pfeil_unten.tga</normaloff>:/grafics/grafics/pfeile/pfeil_unten.tga</iconset>
       </property>
       <property name="iconSize">
        <size>
         <width>50</width>
         <height>50</height>
        </size>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
    </layout>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label_4">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>20</x>
      <y>60</y>
      <width>331</width>
      <height>491</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="frameShape">
     <enum>QFrame::Box</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Umgebungskarte</string>
    </property>
    <property name="alignment">
     <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>510</x>
      <y>270</y>
      <width>131</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>11</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Missionsablauf</string>
    </property>
    <property name="alignment">
     <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>530</x>
      <y>50</y>
      <width>131</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>11</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Programmieren</string>
    </property>
    <property name="alignment">
     <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>779</width>
     <height>20</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources>
  <include location="grafics.qrc"/>
 </resources>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Help would be appreciated and if futher information is required, I'd be happy to help.

Comment: You can try to set layoutStretch - https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html#stretch-factors
And combine it with minimum/maximum width.

Comment: I edited something.

Comment: @bialy It looks promising, but sadly I'm very new to Qt creator, so I try to get most of the things done by using the Qt creator 'Design' function to create my ui. So I don't really know how to apply/set those stretch factors e.g.

Comment: Stretch factor - Number of digits separated by comas is number of items in layout (or layout like item - QGroupBox for example). For example 1,2 will mean that first one will occupy 1/3 of space while second one is 2/3 of space. Then you can tell that 1/3 of space but no more than x (x is maximum width property of item, not available for plain layouts).

Comment: @bialy In theory I got it partially, but I don't know e.g. which function would get 1,2 as its parameters

Comment: It is set from designer window. Look here https://i.imgur.com/FyqWQBf.png

Comment: Just place your lineedit to scrollarea

Comment: @Deep If you meant putting the lineedit inside a scrollarea, it  doesn't work in my case at least. You can see the result above

Comment: @bialy It looks good except that my `centralwidget` doesn't have the index tag `Layout`. https://i.imgur.com/sOA76PO.png

Comment: I'd really really appreciate the help. I'm in total despair, been searching the web for hours and haven't found anything helpful yet ...

Comment: @Cpt.Crazy provide a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc I did all of this with the Qt Creator "Design" tool, so I can give you so code behind it if that's what you mean or I can try to display the problem with a smaller more reduced version of the complete window I'm displaying at  the moment

Comment: @Cpt.Crazy If you have used Qt Designer then provide the .ui in addition to the classes.

Comment: @eyllanesc ah oke, added it ot the question